# Among these 3 duplicate questions, which should be the `root`?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I want to mark the following three questions as duplicates, but I can't decide which one should be the 'root'. All of them are related to the usage of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in a Custom Shortcut within Unity.

- [Custom shortcut for System Monitor not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/1018814/566421) - this one I've answered in a while ago and the suggested solution match to a part of the second question (that still unanswered).
- [Ubuntu 16.04 escape key doesn't work in custom keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/q/961185/566421) - this contains the solution that I suggested, but there is not answer of the main question - why Custom Shortcuts that use <kbd>Esc</kbd> key don't work?
- [Keyboard shortcut Shift + Ctrl + Escape does not work](https://askubuntu.com/q/489418/566421) - this one I found after my answer was accepted. There within the comments is provided the true answer - it is a bug, that is reported on Launchpad with number [#1350527](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1350527) and still not resolved. I've added this information into my answer.

Which of these questions I should choose as the 'root' for the duplication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Custom shortcut for System Monitor not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018814/custom-shortcut-for-system-monitor-not-working), which has an answer that actually explains the problem, is the only candidate.

[Keyboard shortcut Shift + Ctrl + Escape does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489418/keyboard-shortcut-shift-ctrl-escape-does-not-work) has an unsatisfactory answer which failed to work for at least one person, and looks as if its author didn't actually test it. I've downvoted that answer now so the question is unanswered*. Even if we try, the system won't allow closing against an unanswered question unless it's by the same author.

[Ubuntu 16.04 escape key doesn't work in custom keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961185/ubuntu-16-04-escape-key-doesnt-work-in-custom-keyboard-shortcut) has no answers at all.

So, I voted to close both of the unanswered questions against [Custom shortcut for System Monitor not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018814/custom-shortcut-for-system-monitor-not-working).

*<sub>an *unanswered* question has no upvoted or accepted answers. Zero or negative scored answers don't count.</sub>